# How to detect when user receives a role?

Tags: discord.js

I just began trying to learn how to write my first Discord bot this morning so I am very inexperienced with discord.js, but I am familiar with JavaScript. However I have been searching for a couple of hours trying to find a way to call a function whenever a user in my server receives or loses a role.

In my server I have added the Patreon bot which assigns a role to users who become patrons. And I would like to create a custom bot that posts "hooray username" in my general channel when a user receive the patron role.

I can not find any example that shows how to detect when a user gains or loses a role. Is it possible to do this simply using an event? Or would I possibly need to periodically iterate over all users and maintain a list of their current roles while checking for changes?

I apologize that my question doesn't include any code or examples but I haven't made any progress and am reaching out to the SO community for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the event `guildMemberUpdate`.

You can compare the oldMember state to the newMember state and see what roles have changed.

This is not the most elegent solution but will get the job done.

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    // Roles
    const oldRoles = oldMember.roles.cache,
          newRoles = newMember.roles.cache;

    // Has Role?
    const oldHas = oldRoles.has('role-id'),
          newHas = newRoles.has('role-id');

    // Check if removed or added
    if (oldHas && !newHas) {
        // Role has been removed
    } else if (!oldHas && newHas) {
        // Role has been added
    }
});
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate

Answer (score 1):

This is simple with [Client#guildMemberUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate). Here’s some simple code that may help you

(This is the shortest code I could come up with)

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember) => {
if(oldMember.roles.cache.has('patreonRoleId')) return;
if(newMember.roles.cache.has('patreonRoleId')) {
//code here to run if member received role
//Warning: I didn’t test it as I had no time.
}
})
```

To see the removed role, just put the logical NOT operator (!) in front of both of the if statements like this:

```js
if(!oldMember.roles.cache.has('patreonRoleId'))

if(!newMember.roles.cache.has('patreonRoleId'))
```

Note: make sure you have guildMembers intent enabled from the developers portal